# Text box showing some box-shadow on iPhone, iPad and Blackberry Mobiles

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I am developing responsive website. I have given styling to input box like following.

CSS : >

```
input[type="text"] {
border:1px solid #F2F2F2; 
background:none; 
font-size:14px;
font-family:'Raleway';
font-weight:500;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#666666;  
}
```

Now, this all thing works perfectly in desktop as well as Samsung mobiles.

But on iPhone,iPad and Blackberry phone there is some 1 pixel box-shadow coming inside the textbox.

Does anybody faced this kind of issue, if yes than please provide my a solution for it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default iPhone and iPad used safari browser.

And safari shows some inner shadow in the input box by default.

For that you have to use `-webkit-appearance: none;`

So, your code will be like following:

```
input[type="text"] {
-webkit-appearance: none;
border:1px solid #F2F2F2; 
background:none; 
font-size:14px;
font-family:'Raleway';
font-weight:500;
text-transform:uppercase;
color:#666666;  
}
```

I hope it will work with Blackberry too.